# Can we use an adjective after a preposition? - "We found it difficult to judge from wrong"

Tags: prepositions, adjectives

I saw a sentence on the internet like this:

> *We found it difficult to judge from **wrong**.*

Is it right to use adjective ***wrong*** after preposition ***from***?

I wonder about that. Because I learned that ***noun*** only can be used after a preposition.

Can adjective be used after preposition?

Comment: No: preps take complements of may kinds. "I stayed [until **after lunch**]"  (preposition phrase); "It won't last [for **long**]" (adverb phrase); "I left [because ***I was tired**]" (clause); "I regard her [as **a friend**]" (predicative).

Comment: "A small cloud of smoke rose from the glass and the colour of the liquid changed from red to purple, and from purple to a watery green".What about this sentence or "from bad to worse"?

Comment: I doubt that you saw this sentence "on the internet" as you have quoted it. You are more likely to have seen the sentence _"We found it difficult to judge right from wrong."_ In any case, as BillJ says, prepositions can take many kinds of complements, including adjectives like _wrong._ Are you familiar with the definite and indefinite articles (_the_ and _a_) in English? It might be wise to concentrate on such basic matters at this early stage of your study.

Comment: @V.V. The circumpositions "from...to" have "bad" and "worse" as their objects, but there, "bad" and "worse" are so-called "small clauses", and we can understand the phrase so: "went from  [being] bad to [being] worse".